# Updating an old application caused this error => Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: flutter

Installed an app from git-hub to update it, using flutter 1.22.6 (because the app was built using this version) but facing this error when running the code.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:[10.2.1, 17.3.99].
> Required by:
> project :app > com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.15.6
> > Failed to list versions for com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:[15.0.0, 16.0.99].
> Required by:
> project :app > com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.15.6
> > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads-identifier/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads-identifier/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads-identifier/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidd
> en
> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[10.2.1, 16.1.99].
> Required by:
> project :app > com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.15.6
> > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-base.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

Answer (score 1):

For error related to 4XX, replace jcenter() with mavenCentral() in build.gradle file.

```
 repositories {
        google()
        jcenter() //remove this
        mavenCentral() //add this
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

because your project has old dependencies I suggest doing a `Flutter clean`.
but the error says that you don't have permission to download from the link. I think connect to VPN should solve this issue

Comment: I tried flutter clean and flutter pub get, also used VPN but I am still having the same error. Any other solution ?

Comment: edit your question and share android/build.gradle.